# how to check if an input from a user is 1 integer

Tags: java, int

i am asking from the user to type a number and I need to check if the user's answer is only one integer

This is my code:

```
System.out.println("MENU:What do you want to do ? \n1.Buy a new ticket!\n2.Renewal of a ticket\n3.Update the content");
            System.out.println("Type the number of what you want to do ");

            if (!(input.hasNextInt() && input.hasNextByte())) {   // if the input is not an integer and more than one byte 
                System.out.println("ERROR!!Enter an integer value ");
                input.next();
            } else {

                int Read = input.nextInt(); //reads what the user has typed/given
 System.out.println("You entered an integer value! ");
            }
```

i have tried this, and it shows error (which menas it is working)for inputs like these: 34443 22123 cdsfr4d but when i give only 2 or 3 integers like: 34 or 567, it does not show me any error !HOw cam I cnage it in order to show me the correct message

Comment: question: why check for integer and not only for `1`, `2` or  `3`? `22123` is as wrong as `abcd`. I would read the line (as string) and check if it is one of the valid options (in a loop to allow retyping {until correct})

Comment: it doe not work

Comment: why not? would it be correct to accept anything but this three values???

Comment: You should have used `Switch statement` to achieve this.

Comment: with switch how ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `&& input.hasNextByte()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you only want the user to input: 1, 2, or 3 since that's what I'm seeing in your Console menu.

The way I would handle this issue is by using a switch statement and a default case in case they enter anything else.

```
if (!(input.hasNextInt()) {   // if the input is not an integer and more than one 
    System.out.println("ERROR!!Enter an integer value ");
    input.next();
} else {

    int choice = input.nextInt();

    switch (choice) {
        case 1: //If choice is 1

        case 2: // If choice is 2

        case 3: // If choice is 3

        default: // If choice is any other integer
    }

}
```

Switch statements are not commonly used in Java as there are usually better ways to handle these scenarios. Here's some more information on switch statements:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Welcome to the Stack Overflow community, make sure you use Google before you use Stack!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do. But as per your approach it seems like you want to input a number through keyboard and want to check if it is a single digit number or not. If I am right then here we go.

```
public class Tests1 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number");
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    Tests1 obj1=new Tests1();
    System.out.println(obj1.digit(number));
}
    public boolean digit(int num) {
        int count = 0;
        while (num != 0) {
            num = num / 10;
            count++;
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My code check that the number is single digit or  not. If it is a single digit number it return true else return false.